# How to resolve XAML parser Exception in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

Hi I am using a WPF application with MVVM model. I Got XAML parser exception while opening my application form. Its says like

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization,
>   PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I am having this DLL file reference in my project under references folder and also i refered it in my XAML as

```
  "xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation " 
  .
  .
  .

 <DataTemplate>

  // The Below line i am getting that exception

 <telerik:RadColumnSparkline ShowAxis="False" ShowFirstPointIndicator="False" ShowLastPointIndicator="False" ShowHighPointIndicators="False" ShowLowPointIndicators="False" EmptyPointBehavior="DropPoint" ItemsSource="{Binding SizeProfileSparkLine}" Width="140" Height="24"/>

 </DataTemplate>
```

I referred that dll in my project but i am getting this exception. I am not able to find how to solve this problem. Can any one tell me the solution of this problem?

Thanks..

Comment: Probably DataVisualization depends on some other assembly. Did you check InnerException? It usually shows why assembly can not be loaded

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Dave, you're probably not referencing assemblies which Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization relies upon. Your can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out which other assemblies you should be referencing.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization references another assembly which you haven't included. The Telerik documentation should let you know the dependent DLLs.

Comment: Can you please give me a bit more information about it? What is the another assembly? how can i call it on my XAML?

Comment: Your XAML reference is correct however your projects does not include the all the correct references. The Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization file depends on other telerik DLLs to function (I assume). It is these other files which are missing from your project.

Comment: @DaveS, is exactly right about another Telerik dependency dll. Try to add Telerik.Windows.Controls. It's hard to dig through Telerik's documentation sometimes to find which one you need. One of my co-workers simply adds all Telerik assemblies that come in the package, which gets rid of the error. Then deletes them one at a time, till he finds the dependency :)